# Trying to find an algorithm or maybe math?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, math

Take the pathway example below, it has 7 pathways, I create an array of 7 to hold a value for each pathway, the initial values of the array is as follows:

> [1,2,3,4,5,6,7] (see picture: top row array values under the paths where start is)

if at random the user picks pathway 5 which is array index [4] the value returned will be 5.. So far so good.

Now it gets a little confusing, because the user has selected pathway 5. I need to change the array values for the next random choice, I always need the currently selected pathway (5 in this example) to now have an array value of 1 and count up to the right and up to the left, the array values should now look like this

> [5,4,3,2,1,2,3]

If you look at the pathway example picture and follow down each step you will see this happening in the array values under the paths the red box highlights the selected path, hope that makes it clearer, and to the question, is there an algorithm that can do this?

[image: Pathway Example 2]

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Hi, it's not a question really I'm just in need of advice or suggestions to solve the problem in the post, I could try to explain what I need this for but it would probably end up more confusing than the post above.

Comment: After your update it's still not clear to me. It does not help that your picture needs to be read from bottom to top.

Comment: Okay I've updated the post with a new picture taking on board what Jan Doggen suggested hopefully this will help clear things up. thanks

Comment: At the moment this is a bit abstract (though I think it is mainly understandable, so I've voted to reopen). Is the number under each pathway a unit distance? Why has the path in each case been the one selected?

Comment: Hi halfer, no the array value beneath each pathway will be used as an id correlating to the selected path, the path in each case will be chosen at random by the user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every array cell contains the distance of the cell you've chosen plus one, is that it? If so, you can simply solve with a `for` statement:

```
for each index of array:
    array[index] = abs(index - selectedIndex)+1
```

where `selectedIndex` is the index that was picked, and `abs(...)` the modulus function.

Your solution of circular array is quicker, because you just need to show the numbers, and you can calculate the new limits based on the selectedIndex and the previous limits only. This solution provided just cost less memory.

Comment: Hey Fernando Aires thanks for your suggestion, unfortunately it's not what I was looking for I'll try to amend my post to make it clearer. thanks again

Comment: Maybe I didn't understood correctly, but it seems my algorithm solves your examples as well. Is the choice of next element an user choice?

Comment: Hi Fernando, Yes it will be a user choice. Take the pathway example above, it has 7 pathways, I create an array of 7 to hold a value for each pathway, the initial value of the array is [1,2,3,4,5,6,7] if at random the user picks pathway 5 which is array index [4] the value returned will be 5.. So far so good.

Comment: Fernando, I've updated the main post with a better explanation, it wouldn't all fit into the comment above, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: No problem, Douglas, but my proposal still solves, AFAIR. I even created an example code in Python, but the comments session here doesn't accept line break, so it became unreadable. :(

Comment: Fernando, your absolutely correct, I was thinking about it all wrong... Over thinking it maybe, but it's really quite simple, many thanks for your solution. Douglas